# java.security.policy and RMI - classpath issue

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, rmi, java-security-manager

I have an app that uses RMI and works when I have the security policy set to

```
//
// Allow everything for now
//
permission java.security.AllPermission;
```

But, when I try to lock it down with the policy below, I get this exception - which makes me think something about the classpath is off and I need to add something about classpath in the policy, but I don't know what.

Also - any idea why I have to set the socket permissions all the different ways (loopback, name, base ip)?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<clinit>(StatusLogger.java:78)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:61)
```

---

```
grant codeBase "file:/C:/apps/abc/xyz/*" {
    
    //
    // Allow everything for now
    //permission java.security.AllPermission;
    
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "127.0.0.1:*", "accept,connect,resolve";
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:6990", "listen,accept,connect,resolve";
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:6993", "listen,accept,connect,resolve";
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "XPS7590.abc.local", "resolve";
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "192.168.1.125:6993", "listen,accept,connect,resolve";

    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.dir", "read";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "LicenseFilename", "read";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "HostId", "read";

    permission java.io.FilePermission  ".", "read";
    permission java.io.FilePermission  "C:/Apps/abc/xyz/-", "read";
    
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setFactory";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createClassLoader";
    //permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setContextClassLoader";
    

};
```

Comment: Is this class  (class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil) in the path of a directory that has read permissions?

Comment: yes.  It and all the other jars are in the same dir.  Which does have read access.  There would be errors earlier from other jars if not.  Good thing to check though.

Answer (score 1):

This fix for this was to add the following line to my policy file.

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader";
```